# Print two strings

Tags: c, string, console, printf, console-application

I want to print two strings in console

```
int k = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    printf("\ra: %d\n\rb: %d", i*2, i*3);
}
```

I want to get this result:

```
a: 4
b: 6
```

But I get:

```
a: 0
a: 2
a: 4
b: 6
```

Comment: What do you mean "realtime"? The program prints what you tell it to print.

Comment: Methinks your term *realtime* doesn't mean to most what it means to you. I *think* you're trying to show just two lines, with counters visually scrolling through values, finally ending up at your posted desired output. How close was I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that output is that you have just one `\r` before a, but `\n\r` between a and b in the:

```
printf("\ra: %d\n\rb: %d", i*2, i*3);
```

Every cycle, the cursor returns to the beginning of line where b is and it writes OVER it, with new value for a :

```
1st    2nd     3rd run
a=0    a=0    a=0
b=0    a=2    a=2 
       b=3    a=4
              b=6
```

since that is quick, you can see only the last one. It's really not clear what you wanna do, but if you need only the output of the last run, you can write the printf after the cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
...
}
printf("\r\na: %d\n\rb: %d", i*2, i*3);
```

Comment: Btw, you could also use `\t` for tab between those two variables and keep them on one line. That way, every time you print, whole thing is written over `printf("\ra: %d\t\tb: %d", i*2, i*3);`
Some consoles support escape codes like `"\33[1A"` which is in fact code for Up arrow on keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the loop to

```
for (int i = 2; i < k; i++)
```

this will print the result you asked for.

```
a: 4
b: 6
```

Comment: I know but I want that "a" and "b" updated in loop. And in console was only two strings (lines).

Comment: I have printed two strings (lines) in console, just as you asked. Please ask that in the question. `a` and `b` cannot be updated in the loop, because they are not variables.

Comment: I mean that after loop in console I must have only two strings. But this strings updated in loop.

Comment: Have you noticed how rapidly this question is being closed?

Comment: @ARTAGE before this question is closed for being unclear, perhaps you should make it... clearer. I asked a question in comments below your post. It wasn't because I was bored. It was because the *exact* nature of your question is unclear. How about *answering* that by updating the clarity of your question. You can edit your own question, you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a if inside the for like:

```
if (i * 2 == 4)
    printf ...
```

Comment: No. I want print ONLY two string and I want that "b" was updeted.